# How to calculate a hash of const char* with given size and content examination by using standard tools

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

I have a `sub_string` struct and I would like to use standard tools to calculate a hash of it:

```
struct sub_string
{
    const char* ptr;
    size_t size;
};
```

Here are some restrictions:

- It has to be done by standard tools provided by `c++11`.
- `const char*` doesn't have to be NUL-terminated.
- I don't want to use `std::hash<const char*>` specialization, since it computes a hash based on a pointer without content examination.
- I don't want to create a new `std::string{ptr, size}` just to compute a hash.
- I would like to have a `sub_string` hash value to be the same value as `std::string{ptr, size}` hash.
- I don't want to touch implementation details of `std::string`.

How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do what you want without relaxing one of your restrictions.

`std::string`'s precise hashing algorithm is implementation defined. So the only way to mimic it would be to rely on `std::string`'s hashing algorithm either by making a `std::string` or borrowing the implementation manually for your own type. Since you won't rely on `std::string` implementation details (that might let you fake a `std::string` without really constructing one, or manually write a copy of the hashing algorithm it uses), and don't want to construct a `std::string`, you can't accomplish what you want with C++11. You'd need C++17 support to let you make a `std::string_view` (which does have guaranteed correspondence with `std::string`'s hash), and you've already said C++11 is your limit, leaving no other options.